# Fact table design in Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure-sql-database, sql-data-warehouse, azure-synapse

Which is the best index and distribution design for relatively small fact tables (on average 30 million rows per table). The structure of each table is similar to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE FactTable (
    TimeDimensionID INT NOT NULL,
    DimensionID1 VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    DimensionID2 VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    DimensionID3 VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    DimensionID4 VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    Measure1 INT,
    Measure2 FLOAT,
    Measure3 DECIMAL (10.2),
    Measure4 DECIMAL (10,2)
)
```

The union of TimeDimensionID, DimensionID1, DimensionID2, DimensionID3 and DimensionID4 is unique in the fact table. Currently we have a clustered and unique primary key in the 5 fields.

- What is the best indexing and distribution to migrate those tables to SQL Azure Data Warehouse? We are thinking about using CLUSTERED INDEX (DimensionID1, DimensionID2, DimensionID3 and DimensionID4) for the index and hash distribution using the TimeDimensionID field.
- The CLUSTERED INDEX must include the TimeDimensionID field even though the hash distribution is for that field?
- Is this design correct or should we use COLUMN STORE INDEX even though the tables actually have less than 100 millions of rows?
- We should consider using replicated tables for the fact tables?

Answer (score 0):

Some recommendations:

- If possible, please move your DimensionIDs from varchar to int/bigint. You'll get better performance, less storage, and lower costs.
- Forget about clustered indexes for now.
- Create your table hash-distributed, but not on date, that will hotspot your data.
- Create your table as a CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
- Don't replicate your FACT table, but replicate your DIMENSIONS instead.